# How to disallow users' changing ip inside LXC container?

Tags: containers, lxc

Because a valid IP has been decided and allocated by 'lxc.network.ipv4' option in 'lxc.config' file, so I don't want user inside the lxc container to change it to another ip (by commands like ip addr, ifconfig, etc), which might result in ip conflict with other lxc container.

So, how to get over with it?